# Formatting How Resultset is Returned & Displayed in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I apologize in advance for the title, I really didn't know how else to word it.

One table, described below:

```
employee_id int(11) unsigned    NO  MUL 0    
location    int(11) NO  MUL 0    
job_id  int(1)  NO  MUL 0    
current tinyint(1)  NO  MUL 1    
previous    varchar(45) NO           
access  timestamp   NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

`job_id` has 3 possible choices: 1, 2 or 3 and `current` is either 1 or 0 for active or inactive.

The records in this table are stored like below:

```
employee_id  location job_id  current        updated
100001          19         1    0       2014-02-25 11:31:39
100001          19         3    1       2014-02-24 09:53:24
100001          18         1    0       2014-02-25 11:31:39
100001          18         3    1       2014-02-24 09:53:24
```

As you can see, an employee can have up to three possible records per work location.

The problem that i am coming up against is displaying this in a table format in PHP, and I'm not sure if it would work properly if the query was written differently.

[image: Example Image]
In the example above, the employee is already active in Job 1. When a record is added for job 2, the location is duplicated, so technically there could be 3 records for a single facility for this employee. My aim is to display all three jobs, if multiple records exist, on the one line, and if they don't exist, the red X which fires an Ajax to create a record in that job when clicked.

For clarity, the three icons indicate that this employee is either:

1. Active in this job (Green Check)
2. In this job, but inactive (Blue Man)
3. Not Active in this job (No record)

The only alternative that I have found which works is to have one record per location, with three job fields.

Comment: The db column information would be a lot easier to read if you put a line break at the end of each one so that they are on their own line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually somewhat uncomplicated, if you approach it as the pivot query it is.  Use a construct like `MAX(CASE...)` to identify each job per employee/location column and collapse the result down to a single row.  Using two conditions and an `ELSE`, each job will either display `active,inactive` or `NULL`. Use those in your application code to ascribe the correct icons.

```
SELECT 
  employee_id,
  location,
  /* the MAX() aggregate reduces multiple NULLs per group to one row
     since each job_id will produce mostly nulls if unmatched by the current CASE
     for this column */
  MAX(CASE
       WHEN job_id = 1 AND current = 1 THEN 'active'
       WHEN job_id = 1 AND current = 0 THEN 'inactive'
       ELSE NULL
      END) AS job1,
  MAX(CASE
       WHEN job_id = 2 AND current = 1 THEN 'active'
       WHEN job_id = 2 AND current = 0 THEN 'inactive'
       ELSE NULL
      END) AS job2,
  MAX(CASE
       WHEN job_id = 3 AND current = 1 THEN 'active'
       WHEN job_id = 3 AND current = 0 THEN 'inactive'
       ELSE NULL
      END) AS job3
FROM jobs
GROUP BY 
  location,
  employee_id
```

Sorry - I tried to setup a SQLfiddle, but the site is not currently functioning. A quick test in my own database produces a result like this:

```
+-------------+----------+----------+------+--------+
| employee_id | location | job1     | job2 | job3   |
+-------------+----------+----------+------+--------+
|      100001 |       18 | inactive | NULL | active |
|      100001 |       19 | inactive | NULL | active |
+-------------+----------+----------+------+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been beating my head against a wall with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just have a table of jobs where each row is a different job. In each job row you can expand it to see a sub-table of locations that lists the location name and an icon indicating status (and any other columns you need).

This would allow you to be specific to the job and the status of it at each location. It would prevent you from being limited in how many jobs and locations. It would also allow you to do other things specific to the job like editing or deleting inline.

You should have a table for the jobs, one for locations, one for employees, a join table that joins an employee to a job with a date-timestamp, and a join table that joins the job to each location it has and any other pertinent information related to that job at that location.

Comment: I agree with all of the above; however, I can't make alterations to the tables. This is where my question really comes in, is there a way to concatenate the records (max of 3) to display as 1?

[Employee_Id] [Location] [Job1] [Job2] [Job 3]

If any of the fields return blank, then we know to display the Red X.